# I am trying to delete duplicate records using SQL statement. I am using MS Access 2010. Here is my statement:

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, delete-row

I am trying to delete duplicate records using SQL statement. I am using MS Access 2010. Here is my statement:

```
DELETE * FROM table1 where not exists  (SELECT min(col1) FROM table1 GROUP BY col2, col3 );
```

Even though the nested Select statement returns a subset of the records of table1, when I execute the delete statement, it deletes no (0) records.

Comment: I think you need to to DELETE table1.*

Comment: Because subquery does not correlate with outer query and as you say subquery data is returned, then it always `EXISTS` and hence no deletes!

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlation clause.  I'm not sure what the data looks like, but this should work:

```
DELETE *
    FROM table1
    WHERE col1 <> (SELECT MIN(t1.col1)
                   FROM table1 as t1
                   WHERE t1.col2 = table1.col2 AND t1.col3 = table1.col3
                  );
```

I suspect that you are trying for:

```
DELETE *
    FROM table1
    WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(col1) FROM table1 GROUP BY col2, col3);
```

This will also work, assuming that `col1` is unique across all rows (the first version will work as long as `col1` is unique for any pair of `col2`/`col3` values).